Problems using Azure speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber on backend to process data from web app
I am trying to implement flow as follows:

JS web app continuously captures audio using WebAudio API (getUserMedia, which is then processed MediaRecorder)
single channel audio is being sent continuously by MediaRecorder as binary stream over Websockets to python backend
Python websocekt backend sends audio to Azure Cognitive Speech services using python SDK (speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber)

I am unable to get this config working even trying multiple combinations of capture codecs (by specifying mimeType of MediaRecorder) and configuration ConversationTranscriber (by specifying wave_stream_format or compressed_audio_format of speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat instance.
I tried OGG/OPUS codec and passing it through to Speech API however it seems to be unrecognized (I am getting results with empty text detected).
Now I am looking into option of capturing plain PCM audio on frontend and then transcoding it on the fly to MP3 which is accepted by ConversationTranscriber.
ConversationTranscriber Python SDK documentation has limited description of exact formats that can be used.
I am looking for suggestions what is proper combination of frontend codecs,  ConversationTranscriber's AudioStreamFormat configuration and probably some backend audio processing that can make whole setup working.
[EDIT]
Looks that there is incompatibility between audio formats that can be consumed by Speech API and formats produced by MediaRecorder.
Speech API can digest: WAV/PCM, MP3, OPUS in OGG container, FLAC, ALAW in WAV container, MULAW in WAV container, MP4
MediaRecorder is able to produce:
OPUS in WebM container, PMC in WebM Container (using RecordRTC library)
So main question here is how to convert WebM container to any of WAV, OGG, MP4. FFmpeg is not solution here since it is too slow and does not support chunked/continuous transcoding.

you can use libraries like FFmpeg or other audio processing libraries in Python. FFmpeg is powerful and supports a wide range of audio formats and codecs.

ffmpeg processing is to slow for realtime application.

use JavaScript-based audio processing library like libopus.js to decode the Opus audio from the WebM container and then encode it to a format compatible with the Speech API.

use lamejs for MP3 encoding or vorbis.js for OGG encoding.

Real-Time Azure Speech Recognition: Azure, FastAPI & Websockets with webm
I've been trying to figure out a way to achieve it and after a week of several testings I've finally got to the solution (it's not perfect but might help the community).
Demo
Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post images yet, but will update this part when I can do so.
Demostration of the client and server
My experience
Regarding to your request. Well, actually you do not need to convert the audio format from the source for the generated chunks. You can use the same widely supported webm audio format using the 'audio/webm;codecs:opus' for the client side.
The approach here would be to take the audio chunks using the well-known MediaRecorder from the WebAudio API, configure it to take the samples using the 'audio/webm;codecs:opus' format, and then, send each chunk to an API via websocket, for example, a FastAPI with WebSockets enabled. Please see the docs from Triangolo to understand how it works: WebSockets with FastAPI
In any case, it can be good to have an exported file (a final one) just after the websocket client is closed, so I'm considering a records/ folder to save the audio files in .webm format. Your project structure in Python should look like this:
.
├── records/
├── .env
├── Dockerfile
├── requirements.txt
└── websocket.py

Let's get started
1. Install the required dependencies
First, make sure you have all the necessary packages in Python, you can first create a virtual environment with  venv using the following command:
# Create a virtual environment and activate it
python -m venv base
source base/bin/activate

Please, see that I've used python instead of python3 since I have installed the symblink python-is-python3, but you can change it to python3 if the command above does not work for you.
After that, please install the following libraries and generate a requirements.txt file for reproducibility:
# Install the python packages
pip install fastapi websockets azure-cognitiveservices-speech python-dotenv asyncio
# Export the packages used in the project for further use
pip freeze > requirements.txt

Then, install the Gstreamer encoder so Azure Speech Recognition client can use it to transform the webm chunks from the browser to the required PCM audio format.
# Installing GStreamer for audio file convertion
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

These are the explicit words from the Azure documentation:
The Speech SDK and Speech CLI use GStreamer to support different kinds of input audio formats. GStreamer decompresses the audio before it's sent over the wire to the Speech service as raw PCM.
The default audio streaming format is WAV (16 kHz or 8 kHz, 16-bit, and mono PCM). Outside WAV and PCM, the following compressed input formats are also supported through GStreamer:

MP3
OPUS/OGG
FLAC
ALAW in WAV container
MULAW in WAV container
ANY for MP4 container or unknown media format

Please note that for ANY, we are including the webm format.
You can read more about this in their article How to use compressed input audio
Frontend: Simple HTML interface with Javascript
For simplicity, we can create a simple web app aplication using Javascript and plain HTML.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Audio Transcription</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="start_microphone()">Start Recording</button>
    <button onclick="stop_microphone()">Stop Recording</button>
    <script>
        let mediaRecorder;
        let ws;
        /* Handle the websocket audio chunk streaming */
        const start_microphone = async () => {
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'audio/webm;codecs:opus' });
            
            try {
                ws.onopen = () => {
                    console.log("WebSocket connection opened.");
                };

                ws.onmessage = (e) => {
                    console.log("Received message:", e.data);
                };

                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                    if (e.data.size > 0 && ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                        ws.send(e.data);
                        console.log(e.data);
                    }
                };

            mediaRecorder.start(100); // Waits 100ms to send a new data chunk

            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error accessing microphone:", error);
            }
        };

        const stop_microphone = () => {
            if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder.state === "recording") {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
            }
            if (ws) {
                ws.close();
                ws.onclose = () => {
                    console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
                };
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Backend: Real Time Recognition with Azure Speech Service using FastAPI and Websocket
Let's start by creating a new file inside your project folder called websocket.py.
Use the following code to test it out:
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from datetime import datetime
import os
import asyncio

load_dotenv() # Load the environmental variables from .env file

class bcolors: # Only to apply colors to the prints
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    
app = FastAPI() # Create a new FastAPI app

# Speech key and region from your Azure Speech Recognition service
speech_key = os.getenv("SPEECH_KEY")
speech_region = os.getenv("SPEECH_REGION")

def create_speech_recognizer(loop, queue):
    """
    Allows to create a client for the speech recognizer and a stream (buffer)
    """
    # Create the configuration of the recognizer from your account of Azure
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(
        subscription=speech_key, 
        region=speech_region
    )

    # Configuration for the input audio format. The documentation specifies that you can use GStreamer (It also needs to be installed locally) to encode other formats to PCM (Pulse Code Modulation). 
    # Here I'm using speechsdk.AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY since i'm sending streaming data using the audio/webm;codecs:opus format directl, that is supported for most of the modern browsers 
    format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(compressed_stream_format=speechsdk.AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY) # To receive audio data in any format and process them with GStreamer
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(format) # Creates an audio stream to send data to the speech service
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream) # Adjust the audio config using the recently created stream

    # Creates a speech recognizer client for the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(
        speech_config=speech_config, 
        audio_config=audio_config,
        language="en-US" # Change to your desired language if supported. If not specified, 'en-US' will be used by default.
    )

    # Callbacks for the speech recognizer. They are automatically triggered based on event type
    def recognizing_cb(evt: speechsdk.SpeechRecognitionEventArgs):
        """
        Triggered everytime the recognizer has processed a set of audio chunks and recognized part of the speech
        """
        print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}Azure Speech Recognition -> Recognizing: {evt.result.text}{bcolors.ENDC}")

    def recognized_cb(evt: speechsdk.SpeechRecognitionEventArgs):
        """
        Triggered when the speech recognition has processed an audio fragment and recognized the text in its entirety
        """
        print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}Azure Speech Recognition -> Recognized: {evt.result.text}{bcolors.ENDC}")
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(queue.put(evt.result.text), loop)

    def stop_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        """
        Triggered when speech recognition session is stopped
        """
        print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Azure Speech Recognition -> Session stopped due websocket close: {evt}{bcolors.ENDC}")

    def canceled_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        """
        Triggered when the speech recognition session is cancelled due to an error
        """
        print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}Azure Speech Recognition -> Session canceled due an error: {evt}{bcolors.ENDC}")

    # Connect callbacks to the speech recognizer to be triggered when an event occurs.
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(recognizing_cb)
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_cb)
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(canceled_cb)

    return speech_recognizer, stream

@app.websocket("/ws") # Change to your desired websocket endpoint
async def audio_streaming(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept() # Accept client connection
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Get the asyncio event loop
    message_queue = asyncio.Queue() # Create a message queue to store the results of speech recognition
    
    speech_recognizer, stream = create_speech_recognizer(loop, message_queue) # Create the speech recognizer and the audio stream

    async def receive_audio(websocket, stream):
        audio_data = b"" # Store the audio data in bytes
        print(f"{bcolors.OKGREEN}WebSocket -> Receiving audio from client and saving into stream...{bcolors.ENDC}")
        while True: # As long as the customer is connected
            try: # Attempt to receive audio data from the client
                data = await websocket.receive_bytes()  # Receive audio data from the client
                audio_data += data  # Store audio all data chunks in a variable

                stream.write(data)  # Write audio data to the stream buffer

                print(f"{bcolors.OKCYAN}WebSocket -> Stream data en bytes: {len(data)}{bcolors.ENDC}", end="\n")  # Data that are being sent from the client
            except WebSocketDisconnect:  # If the client is disconnected
                print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}Azure Speech Recognition -> Stream closed{bcolors.ENDC}")
                stream.close()  # Close the stream

                print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}API -> Websocket client disconnected!{bcolors.ENDC}")
                print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}API -> Stopping continuous recognition...{bcolors.ENDC}")
                speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition() # Stop speech recognition
                print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}API -> Continuous recognition stopped!{bcolors.ENDC}")
                print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}API -> Exporting audio data to a file...{bcolors.ENDC}")
                # Save received audio data to a file
                with open(f"records/received_audio_{datetime.now()}.webm", "wb") as f: # Create an audio file in webm format
                    f.write(audio_data) # Write the whole audio data to the file
                    print(f"{bcolors.OKBLUE}API -> Audio data exported!{bcolors.ENDC}")
                break
            except Exception as e: # If an error occurs
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                break # Exiting the loop

    async def send_messages():
        """
        Allows messages recognized by the Azure service to be sent to the client via the websocket to the client
        """
        while True: # As long as the customer is connected
            message = await message_queue.get() # Get the recognized text from the queue
            await websocket.send_text(message) # Send the text to the websocket client

    try:
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition() # Start continuous speech recognition
        print("API -> Continuous recognition running, say something to process data...")
        await asyncio.gather(receive_audio(websocket, stream), send_messages()) # Execute the functions of receiving audio and sending messages back to the client.

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")


If you already read the code above, you will realize these lines of code are doing the magic here, setting up the recognizer in order to use the GStreamer to encode automatically the webm to PCM using the collected chunks over time!
format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(compressed_stream_format=speechsdk.AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY)
stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(format)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)

After copying the code inside the websocket.py file, create an .env file with the environmental variables for testing.
Note: Don't forget to exclude this file in a .gitignore file if you have initiated the repository.
SPEECH_KEY="<your-speech-key>"
SPEECH_REGION="<your-speech-region>"

After these steps, you will be able to test the recongnizer. Execute the following command:
fastapi run websocket.py

You should see something like this:
INFO     Using path websocket.py                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO     Resolved absolute path /home/username/azure-speech-recognition-streaming-websocket/websocket.py                                                                                    
INFO     Searching for package file structure from directories with __init__.py files                                                                                                              
INFO     Importing from /home/username/azure-speech-recognition-streaming-websocket                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 ╭─ Python module file ─╮                                                                                                                                                                          
 │                      │                                                                                                                                                                          
 │   websocket.py     │                                                                                                                                                                          
 │                      │                                                                                                                                                                          
 ╰──────────────────────╯                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO     Importing module websocket                                                                                                                                                                
INFO     Found importable FastAPI app                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 ╭── Importable FastAPI app ───╮                                                                                                                                                                   
 │                             │                                                                                                                                                                   
 │  from websocket import app  │                                                                                                                                                                   
 │                             │                                                                                                                                                                   
 ╰─────────────────────────────╯                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO     Using import string websocket:app                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 ╭─────────── FastAPI CLI - Production mode ───────────╮                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                     │                                                                                                                                           
 │  Serving at: http://0.0.0.0:8000                    │                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                     │                                                                                                                                           
 │  API docs: http://0.0.0.0:8000/docs                 │                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                     │                                                                                                                                           
 │  Running in production mode, for development use:   │                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                     │                                                                                                                                           
 │  fastapi dev                                        │                                                                                                                                           
 │                                                     │                                                                                                                                           
 ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO:     Started server process [24953]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Deploy the FastAPI app into a Docker Container.
Finally, if you want to run the code inside a container, first you need to create the Dockerfile  in the project folder as follows:
# Gets a lightweight version for Python
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Creates a directory and moves to it
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the source code from your current working directory to the newly created directory inside the container
ADD . /app

# Install all the dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Install the GStreamer to convert from webm to PCM (important to install, otherwise won't work)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

# Expose the port 8000, it's commonly used by FastAPI
EXPOSE 8000

# Runs the FastAPI application for production
CMD ["fastapi", "run", "websocket.py"]

and build it using
docker build -t mycontainer:latest .

and finally, you can run it using
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 mycontainer:latest

I hope this information can be very helpul and send your valuable feedback if something can be improved.

Thanks. This helped a lot.
Though, I'm getting an error from G-streamer like :-
[791866]: 340292740ms SPX_TRACE_ERROR:  base_gstreamer.cpp:211 Error from GStreamer: Source: typefind
Message: Stream doesn't contain enough data.
DebugInfo: ../plugins/elements/gsttypefindelement.c(1012): gst_type_find_element_chain_do_typefinding (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstDecodeBin:decodebin/GstTypeFindElement:typefind:
Can't typefind stream


I am looking for suggestions what is proper combination of frontend codecs, ConversationTranscriber's AudioStreamFormat configuration and probably some backend audio processing that can make whole setup working.

Use the WebAudio API to capture audio in PCM format. set up MediaRecorder to capture the PCM audio stream. check that the sample rate and bit depth are appropriate for speech recognition tasks (commonly 16 kHz sample rate and 16-bit depth).
Frontend :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Audio Transcription</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="startRecording()">Start Recording</button>
    <button onclick="stopRecording()">Stop Recording</button>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lamejs/1.2.0/lame.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/libopus.js/dist/opus-stream-decoder.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let mediaRecorder;
        let audioChunks = [];

        async function startRecording() {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
                const webmBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
                transcodeToMP3(webmBlob);
            };

            mediaRecorder.start();
        }

        function stopRecording() {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        }

        function transcodeToMP3(webmBlob) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function() {
                const opusData = new OggOpusDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(reader.result));
                const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 16000, 128); // Mono, 16 kHz sample rate, 128 kbps
                const mp3Data = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(opusData);
                sendAudioToBackend(mp3Data);
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(webmBlob);
        }

        function sendAudioToBackend(mp3Data) {
            const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8765');
            ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            ws.onopen = function() {
                ws.send(mp3Data);
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>


The collected audio chunks (in WebM format) are then transcoded to MP3 using libopus.js and lamejs.
The resulting MP3 audio data is sent to the backend via WebSocket.
You can use JavaScript libraries like lamejs or libmp3lame.js for in-browser MP3 encoding.

Backend :
import asyncio
import websockets
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import SpeechConfig, ConversationTranscriber

async def process_audio(websocket, path):
    async for audio_data in websocket:
        # Configure ConversationTranscriber
        speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="your_subscription_key", region="your_region")
        speech_config.speech_recognition_language = "en-US"
        transcriber = ConversationTranscriber(speech_config)

        # Process audio stream
        result = await transcriber.recognize_once_async(audio_data)

        # Handle transcription result
        if result.reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
        elif result.reason == ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized")
        elif result.reason == ResultReason.Canceled:
            cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
            print("Speech Recognition canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
            if cancellation_details.reason == CancellationReason.Error:
                print("Error details: {}".format(cancellation_details.error_details))

start_server = websockets.serve(process_audio, "localhost", 8765)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


When audio data is received from the frontend, it is processed using the Azure Cognitive Speech service for transcription.
The transcription result is printed to the console.


Generally speaking, the preferred audio format is PCM audio 16 bits per sample, 16KHz sampling rate, and mono. However, you can use compressed audio formats using GStreamer. You can find more details on using compressed audio with the Speech SDK here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/ai-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=pivots=programming-language-python
